# How to use value of one method in another inside same class in Ionic?

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to use the data received from my API call in IONIC `home.ts` in google map method in `home.ts` .But it ended up giving a null or undefined error.

How can I use the data from one method in another?

Here is my `home.ts` code

```
getResturentDetails(id){
    const data = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
    this.userPostData.api_token= data;
    this.userPostData.resturentId= id;

    this.authService.postData(this.userPostData,'resturentDetail').then((result)=>{
        this.responseData = result;
        console.log(this.responseData); //I can see data as expected

    })
}
```

Output of the console log is something like this

```
{"id":"1","lat":"10.90" ,"lon":"89.00"}
```

Something like this in JSON object notation

My constructor

```
 constructor(public nav: NavController,
    public navParams:NavParams,
    public tripService: TripService,
    public authService:AuthServiceProvider
  ) {
    // set sample data

    this.getResturentDetails(this.navParams.get('id'));
     console.log(this.responseData.lat); //saying undefined index lat
     console.log(this.responseData.lon); //saying undefined index lon
    this.DisplayMap(this.responseData.lat,this.responseData.lon); 
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {

  }
```

So how do I handle this issue ??
And in case if my API return an array of data, in that case how to handle the issue
For example, if the API response is something like this

```
[{"id":"1","lat":"10.90" ,"lon":"89.00"},{"id":"2","lat":"10.90" ,"lon":"89.00"}]
```

Something like this in JSON format in that case how to handle the issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code like this :

```
constructor(...) {
    ...
    this.getResturentDetails(this.navParams.get('id')).then(result => {
        this.responseData = result;
        console.log(this.responseData.lat); // will not say undefined index lat
        console.log(this.responseData.lon); //will not say undefined index lon
        this.DisplayMap(this.responseData.lat,this.responseData.lon); 
    })
}

getResturentDetails(id){
    const data = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
    this.userPostData.api_token= data;
    this.userPostData.resturentId= id;

    return this.authService.postData(this.userPostData,'resturentDetail');
}
```

> **Reason why its not working is , async behaviour :**
>
> Just follow the Execution sequence No in below code , you will get the idea how the
>   flow will go in real time execution

```
// this will call getResturentDetails , and consider it may take few sec
this.getResturentDetails(this.navParams.get('id'));  // Execution sequence : 1

// next line will be executed before result returns coz of async behaviour
console.log(this.responseData.lat); // Execution sequence : 6
console.log(this.responseData.lon); // Execution sequence : 7
this.DisplayMap(this.responseData.lat,this.responseData.lon); // Execution sequence : 8 

getResturentDetails(id){
    const data = localStorage.getItem('userToken'); // Execution sequence : 2
    this.userPostData.api_token= data; // Execution sequence : 3
    this.userPostData.resturentId= id; // Execution sequence : 4

    // Execution sequence : 5
    this.authService.postData(this.userPostData,'resturentDetail').then((result)=>{ 
        this.responseData = result; // Execution sequence : 9
        console.log(this.responseData); // Execution sequence : 10

    })
}
```

Comment: That was amazing vivek :)
Thank you so much that work amazingly and your explanation was very nice too :)
If it not much trouble to ask, can you please tell me what if the api return an array . and i want to store all the lat long in array ,in order to display multiple markers . shall i loop them before calling map method and store them in an array ?

Comment: @user7747472 , Thanks for the appreciation :) , and  Yes you are right about the array , you should try it out .